# Error When Clearing browser Cookie c#

Tags: c#, watin

I want to clear all cookies in my IE with code below:

```
public void ClearCookie()
    {
        string[] Cookies =
            System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache));
        foreach (string currentFile in Cookies)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(currentFile);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I run, a messageBox appeares with content: **The process cannot access the file: C:\User...\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary InterNet Files\counter.dat' because it is being used by another process**
What should I do to fix that problem???

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching the general Exception, you can focus on specifying the exact error type, like:

```cs
        try
        {
            File.Delete(currentFile);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // file is locked, in use or has an open handle in another application
            // so skip it
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // you don't have permissions to delete the file
        }
```

This should give you a better indication on how to handle the diversity of File IO Exceptions that can occur. Also, have a look at [MSDN's File.Delete documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) for more information of the different types of error this method can throw.

Comment: thank you guy, it's fixed. But after I clear Cookie, I login to a website, and password is still auto filled. I wonder if the cookie hasn't been deleted yet ???

Comment: Credentials shouldn't be stored in cookies, but are mostly stored per browser in a different, more secure way. So, deleting the Temporary Internet Files isn't the same as clearing the entire browser's history.

Comment: Oh really, can you show me how to clear all history by code, I actually nead it

Comment: That's a different question all together and I'd like to suggest asking it as smart as you can as you can in a new thread.